# Enable port RA0 as input and retrieve value LDR from led

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, pic, microchip

I'm using the picdem 18F4550 with microchip v8.63 with the C18 compiler.

I will enable PortA to set as input, I will connect a LDR on port RA0.
Which is as following (I think)

```
TRISAbits.TRISA0 = 1; <= set RA0 as input
```

Now I want the value of the LDR (voltage/value if a led is on), can I say:

```
int colorLed = PortAbits.RA0;
```

And now in the variable of type int there is the value/voltage of my Led.

Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Cross-posting is discouraged. (http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12176/enable-port-ra0-as-input-and-retrieve-value-ldr-from-led)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want to measure an analogue voltage, in which case you will need to use the pin as `AN0`, rather than `RA0`.  You should read section 21 of the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39632e.pdf), but in summary, you will need to configure the A-D converter using registers `ADCON0`, `ADCON1` and `ADCON2`, and read the result that's present on `ADRESH:ADRESL`.

Note that you *could* potentially read the LDR using a digital input, but you will be unable to calibrate it.  Using the analogue input is slightly more complicated, but much more flexible.

Comment: Worth noting that that RA0 is multiplexed with AN0. The pin must be configured for the AN0 function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I just ask to enable The RA0 as input, and jou give me the wrong datasheet, I have the datasheet for c compiler with 18F4550. But I didn't find to enable this port.

Comment: @yannick: That is the correct datasheet.  Simply using RA0 as the input will not work in this situation; you will need to use that pin as an analogue input, in which case it's called AN0.

Comment: @yannick, an analogue input using the ADC will read the Voltage not the Resistance of the LDR, so arrange your circuit so that there is a voltage across the LDR eg as a potential divider. The ADC input will not provide a voltage to measure your resistance.

Answer (score 0):

PORTA can function as a digital input or analog input, by default.

To use an LDR you most likely need to to configure the PIN as analog input.

HOwever it still depends on what you want to do. Maybe you should give a bit mroe details as to your project.

check this link for the PIC18F4550 [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39632e.pdf)

You can only find more detailed resources on the PIC184550 [here](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en010300)

again, you might want to give more details on your application so we can help you better.

Comment: it is the purpose if an LED comes on (eg red on port RB4). then the LDR detect this and I want the value of which led, to stored in a variable. then, (I have already created a program for), the microprocessor with boxes play this color in sound (speaks 'red'). You can call my project a "color sensor " . The purpose is for blind people can "see" color by playback sound. Hopefully my explanation is clearer in my efforts.

Comment: An LDR alone cannot differentiate colors, it only responds to the intensity of light, and that is not enough to determine color. tryout this [link](http://www.electronic-circuits-diagrams.com/sensorsimages/sensorsckt3.shtml), The circuit does something similar to what you're trying to do. You will need 3LDRs to detect the intensity of RED, GREEN and BLUE separately, and use the intensity reading to determine which color of light fell on it. So to the basics, the LDRs must be connected to analog pins. Also, check this [link](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8663) for a color detection chip.